# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is the piece of code that I am using :

```
if (config.getTruststore() != null) { // If there is a custom stargate-filter.truststore set in application.properties - load it. Otherwise use default JDK truststore.
  ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
  URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(config.getTruststore());
  if (resource == null) {
    System.out.println("Could not find the truststore located at [" + config.getTruststore() + "]");
  } else {
    File file = new File(resource.toURI()); // Error line 
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ks.load(fis, config.getTruststorePassword().toCharArray());
  }
}
```

Its working fine in eclipse but getting exception while deploying onto server. More over this is inbuilt utility and I cannt make any changes in this code.

I have springboot project with my jks file  at resource folder and in my application prop I have defined it as :

```
stargate-filter.truststore=/standard_trusts.jks
```

OR

```
stargate-filter.truststore=standard_trusts.jks..
```

NOT WORKING BOTH ways

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: Small suggestion: since the path is in a property and you are using Spring, wouldn't the best way to do what you are trying to do be injecting the property value in the class and/or using the Resource class from Spring to read the keystore file? Maybe you can even inject the Resource directly, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Did you verify the contents? What is the bundle? jar?

Comment: I am assuming that it is jar and you are doing the mistake of using `getResource`. You need to use `getResourceAsStream` instead.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat : The above piece of code is in inbuild jar .. that I imported in my project ... I cannot do any changes in the code .. except I can place this .jks file some where outside .. but still the path is not picked up

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: